# How do I read in a line of text that contains commas?

Tags: string, input, fortran

Funny that I have never met this problem before in my whole career for some reason, but I cannot use `READ(9,*)STRING`, where `STRING` is `CHARACTER*n` to work.

The reason is, commas delimit the string on input and other characters probably do horrible control things too. I simply want to read in the whole line up to CRLF. Surely there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to use character format descriptor on read:

```
READ(UNIT=9,FMT='(A)')STRING
```